# List renders incorrectly

Tags: lists, fontspec, bidi

In output of following LaTeX markup, the list is rendered incorrectly. What is wrong with it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\faFont[Script=Arabic]{Tahoma}   
\usepackage{bidi}
\newenvironment{Fa}{\begin{RTL}\faFont}{\end{RTL}}
\newcommand{\fa}[1]{\faFont\RL{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Test
\item
Test
\item
This is Persian word:\fa{آزمایش} OK?
\item
Test
\item
Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: place the `\fa` bit in a group, ie `{\fa{stuff}}`   (What's happening is you're selecting the font, but not 'deselecting' it, as it were.  You can also place the group in the definition, to set it and forget it.)

Comment: Also, are you using `xetex`??

Comment: @SeanAllred: Obviously he is, there is a `fontspec` package.

Comment: @m0nhawk I didn't notice at first; it was only when `latex` through up on me did I figure it out ;)

Comment: Just stick it in the definition of `\fa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be simplified like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tahoma}
\newcommand{\fa}[1]{{\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Tahoma}#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Test
    \item This is Persian word: \fa{آزمایش} OK?
    \item Test
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @PHPst: Thanks for noticing. I'm currently looking into making this without additional command.

Comment: I extremely need that. I will be thankful if you find out a easier way for inserting Arabic scripts in Latin documents.

Comment: Do you find any way to that without additional command?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is selecting `faFont` without *deselecting* it.  Place the changes in a group in the definition to make it local:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\faFont[Script=Arabic]{Tahoma}   
\usepackage{bidi}
\newenvironment{Fa}{\begin{RTL}\faFont}{\end{RTL}}
\newcommand{\fa}[1]{{\faFont\RL{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Test
\item
Test
\item
This is Persian word:\fa{آزمایش} OK?
\item
Test
\item
Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

<strike>I would add output, but I don't use `xetex` or LuaTeX; my apologies.</strike> Two years adds some perspective :)

[image]